# Analytics with postback

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, urbanairship.com, clevertap

We are currently using GA for logging events, Urban airship for InApp notifications/re-engagement, Apsalar for attribution.

Using notification driven re-engagement has improved our metrics and revenue so we are exploring more comprehensive re-engagement (Email, SMS).

There are some tools in the market (Clevertap, Netcore) which offer the bouquet of notification, email and sms but to achieve that we have to share a lot of data and user's email and mobile with them.

Ideally we would like a service which can send a postback to our server with event name and parameters so we can take necessary action. This helps us have a better privacy policy, cheaper email and sms delivery.

Apsalar does offer postback but only for install event.

Is there any solution which we can integrate to achieve this. Better if it works across platforms (iOS, Android and Web)

Comment: Let me know in case this is not the right forum or the question needs to be changed to adhere to any guidelines.

Comment: This rather sounds like you are asking for a software recommendation: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you looked into Urban Airship Connect? You can use the [webhooks integration](https://docs.urbanairship.com/connect/webhooks/) to post mobile event data to your servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CleverTap [Webhooks](https://support.clevertap.com/docs/dashboard-user-guide/working-with-webhooks.html) to send data back to your servers, and then you can choose either to consume the data or act upon it.

Hope this helps.

ob disc: I'm the founder of CleverTap.

Comment: There are two ways events are generated in clevertap, one which app triggers (for ex. transaction), second which clevertap detects (for ex. uninstall, inactivity). Does webhook support both these type of events?

Comment: webhooks can work for "derived events" also. You need to define a segment - say, users who've added to cart but haven't transacted within 10 since then. You can then route this segment as a webhook to your backend. So yes, CleverTap does support both types of events.